# Cant append elements to FormData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with JavaScript not being able to append elements to my FormData object.
This is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File uploading</h1>
<div id="response"></div>
    <form action="index/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmSave">
            <input class="fileUpload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>          
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
```

Javascript code is as under

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.fileUpload').change(function(e){
       var formData = new FormData();
       var file = $(this)[0].files;
       formData.append('file', file);
       //console.log(formData); // it's empty!
       // show loading text
       $("#response").html("Uploading file... Please wait");

       // Do upload process, AJAX Post
       $.ajax({
         url: 'index/upload',
         type : "POST",
         data: formData,
         processData : false,
         contentType : false,
         success : function(res) {           
           $("#response").html(res);
           // Show the remove button
         }
       });   

    });
```

I'm trying to do an AJAX POST to my Webserver ( PHP ) this works perfect but I keep getting the exception message that there are no files in my FormData object.

Please help.

Thanks!

UPDATE :

It looks like you cant view the formData object in the console, console.log(formData).
The POST works just fine. On the PHP side I just basically loop through the $_FILES.

Thanks all for your input.

Comment: $.each(file, function(key, value)
    {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var formObj = new FormData($('form')[0]); //try like this
```

My sample working example,

```
var formObj = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        //formObj.append('test','CodingAnt');
        $.ajax({
          url: 'upload.php',
          data: formObj,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          dataType:'json',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data.path);
            $('#image_uploaded').attr('src',data.path);
            $('#image_uploaded').show()
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery `serialize()` method

```
<script>


// The Javascript

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.fileUpload').change(function(e){

    // show loading text
        $("#response").html("Uploading file... Please wait");

    // Do upload process, AJAX Post
       $.ajax({
         url: 'index/upload',
         type : "POST",
         data: $('form').serialize(),
         processData : false,
         contentType : false,
         success : function(res) {           
           $("#response").html(res);
           // Show the remove button
         }
       });   

    });
</script>
```